# Java - Call Method from sub class By pressing a JButton in the base class

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

Can I call a method from an extended class by pressing a JButton?
I know how to display messages etc when pressing a JButton, but I want to know if it is possible to do this?

I want to call methods from Activate_and_Deactivate class to use as action performed by pressing radiobuttons ON and OF. I can directly place the statements in the actionevent argument but the teacher said I have to use inheritance atleast for something.

this is my code.

```
package Calculators;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
public class UIFrame {
    Activate_and_Deactivate act = new Activate_and_Deactivate();
    JButton button0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton button_Div = new JButton("/");
    JButton button_C = new JButton("C");
    JButton button_Mul = new JButton("*");
    JButton button_Add = new JButton("+");
    JButton button_Sub = new JButton("-");
    JButton button_Dot = new JButton(".");
    JButton button_rec = new JButton("1/x");
    JButton button_Sqr = new JButton("\u221A");
    JButton button_neg = new JButton("±");  
    JButton button_per = new JButton("%");
    JButton button_equal = new JButton("=");
    JButton button_undo = new JButton("\u2190");
    JButton btnExit = new JButton("exit");      
    JRadioButton rdbtnOn = new JRadioButton("On");
    JRadioButton rdbtnOff = new JRadioButton("Off");

    private JFrame frmCalculator;
    private JTextField screen;
    private JTextField value1;
    private JTextField value2;
    private JLabel operation;


    double fNumber = 0;
    double sNumber = 0;
    double result = 0;



    String ope;
    String answer;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");       //Motif, and Windows packages that it requires are shipped with the Java SDK this way
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIFrame window = new UIFrame();
                    window.frmCalculator.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public UIFrame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmCalculator = new JFrame();
        frmCalculator.setTitle("Java calculator ver 3.1.6 by Muhammad Haroon");
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frmCalculator.setBounds(100, 100, 326, 422);
        frmCalculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        value1 = new JTextField();
        value1.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        value1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
        value1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        value1.setBorder(null);
        value1.setBounds(151, 52, 141, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(value1);
        value1.setColumns(10);

        value2 = new JTextField();
        value2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        value2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        value2.setBorder(null);
        value2.setBounds(71, 90, 218, 37);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(value2);
        value2.setColumns(10);

        operation = new JLabel("");
        operation.setForeground(new Color(144, 238, 144));
        operation.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        operation.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        operation.setBounds(20, 97, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(operation);

        screen = new JTextField();
        screen.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED, null, null), new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null)));
        screen.setEditable(false);
        screen.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        screen.setBounds(10, 48, 289, 82);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(screen);
        screen.setColumns(10);


        rdbtnOn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                act.activate();
            }
        });
        rdbtnOn.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        rdbtnOn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        rdbtnOn.setBounds(11, 18, 38, 23);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(rdbtnOn);


        rdbtnOff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                act.deactivate();
            }
        });
        rdbtnOff.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        rdbtnOff.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        rdbtnOff.setBounds(51, 18, 38, 23);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(rdbtnOff);


        button0.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String num = value2.getText() + button0.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button0.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button0.setBounds(11, 306, 110, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button0);


        button2.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button2.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });


        button1.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button1.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button1.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button1.setBounds(11, 264, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button1);
        button2.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button2.setBounds(71, 264, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button2);


        button3.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button3.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button3.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button3.setBounds(131, 264, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button3);


        button4.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button4.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button4.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button4.setBounds(11, 222, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button4);


        button5.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button5.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button5.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button5.setBounds(71, 222, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button5);


        button6.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button6.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button6.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button6.setBounds(131, 222, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button6);


        button7.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button7.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button7.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button7.setBounds(11, 180, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button7);


        button8.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button8.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button8.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button8.setBounds(71, 180, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button8);


        button9.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = value2.getText() + button9.getText();          //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button9.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button9.setBounds(131, 180, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button9);


        button_Div.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_Div.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                value1.setText(value2.getText());
                operation.setText("/");
                value2.setText(null);

            }
        });


        button_C.setBackground(new Color(60, 179, 113));
        button_C.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                value2.setText(null);
                value1.setText(null);
                operation.setText(null);
            }
        });
        button_C.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_C.setBounds(71, 138, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_C);
        button_Div.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_Div.setBounds(191, 180, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_Div);


        button_Mul.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_Mul.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                value1.setText(value2.getText());
                operation.setText("*");
                value2.setText(null);
            }
        });
        button_Mul.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_Mul.setBounds(191, 222, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_Mul);


        button_Add.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_Add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                value1.setText(value2.getText());
                operation.setText("+");
                ope = "+";
                value2.setText(null);

            }
        });
        button_Add.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_Add.setBounds(191, 306, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_Add);


        button_Sub.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_Sub.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                value1.setText(value2.getText());
                operation.setText("-");
                value2.setText(null);
            }
        });
        button_Sub.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_Sub.setBounds(191, 264, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_Sub);


        button_Dot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String num = value2.getText() + button_Dot.getText();           //value.setText(value.getText()+Button)
                value2.setText(num);
            }
        });
        button_Dot.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_Dot.setBounds(131, 306, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_Dot);


        button_rec.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_rec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                double ops1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(value2.getText()));
                double ops2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(value2.getText()));
                ops1 = 1/ops2;
                value2.setText(String.valueOf(ops1));
                value1.setText("reciproc("+String.valueOf(ops2)+")");
            }
        });

                                                //ALT+251
        button_Sqr.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_Sqr.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                double ops = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(value2.getText()));
                ops = Math.sqrt(ops);
                value2.setText(String.valueOf(ops));
                value1.setText("sqrt("+String.valueOf(ops*ops)+")");
            }
        });
        button_Sqr.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        button_Sqr.setBounds(131, 138, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_Sqr);
        button_rec.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        button_rec.setBounds(249, 222, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_rec);

                                                //ALT+0177
        button_neg.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_neg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                double ops = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(value2.getText()));
                ops = ops * (-1);
                value2.setText(String.valueOf(ops));
                value1.setText("negate("+String.valueOf(ops*-1)+")");
            }
        });
        button_neg.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_neg.setBounds(191, 138, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_neg);


        button_per.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
        button_per.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                double ops = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(value2.getText()));
                ops = ops * (100);
                value2.setText(String.valueOf(ops));
                value1.setText(String.valueOf(ops));
            }
        });
        button_per.setBounds(249, 180, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_per);


        button_equal.setBackground(new Color(60, 179, 113));
        button_equal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fNumber = Double.parseDouble(value1.getText());
                sNumber = Double.parseDouble(value2.getText());

                if(operation.getText().equals("+"))
                {
                    result = fNumber + sNumber ; 
                    value1.setText(null);
                    value2.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                }
                else if(operation.getText().equals("-"))
                {
                    result = fNumber - sNumber ; 
                    value1.setText(null);
                    value2.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                }
                else if(operation.getText().equals("*"))
                {
                    result = fNumber * sNumber ; 
                    value1.setText(null);
                    value2.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                }
                else if(operation.getText().equals("/"))
                {
                    result = fNumber / sNumber ; 
                    value1.setText(null);
                    value2.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                }

            }
        });

                                    //ALT+8592
        button_undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String bkspace = null;
                if(value2.getText().length() > 0)
                {

                    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder(value2.getText());
                    strB.deleteCharAt(value2.getText().length() - 1);
                    bkspace = strB.toString();
                    value2.setText(bkspace);
                }               
            }
        });
        button_undo.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 19));
        button_undo.setBounds(10, 138, 50, 31);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_undo);
        button_equal.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        button_equal.setBounds(249, 264, 50, 73);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(button_equal);


        btnExit.setBackground(new Color(255, 99, 71));
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        btnExit.setBounds(11, 348, 51, 23);
        frmCalculator.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

    }

    /**
     * @return the activate_and_Deactivate
     */
    public Object getActivate_and_Deactivate() {
        return Activate_and_Deactivate;
    }

    /**
     * @param activate_and_Deactivate the activate_and_Deactivate to set
     */
    public void setActivate_and_Deactivate(Object activate_and_Deactivate) {
        Activate_and_Deactivate = activate_and_Deactivate;
    }


}














package Calculators;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class Activate_and_Deactivate extends UIFrame 
{
    public void activate()
    {
        button0.setEnabled(true);
        button1.setEnabled(true);
        button2.setEnabled(true);
        button3.setEnabled(true);
        button4.setEnabled(true);
        button5.setEnabled(true);
        button6.setEnabled(true);
        button7.setEnabled(true);
        button8.setEnabled(true);
        button9.setEnabled(true);
        button_Div .setEnabled(true);
        button_C .setEnabled(true);
        button_Mul.setEnabled(true);
        button_Add.setEnabled(true);
        button_Sub.setEnabled(true);
        button_Dot.setEnabled(true);
        button_rec.setEnabled(true);
        button_Sqr.setEnabled(true);
        button_neg.setEnabled(true);
        button_per .setEnabled(true);
        button_equal.setEnabled(true);
        button_undo .setEnabled(true);
        btnExit .setEnabled(true);
        rdbtnOff.setEnabled(true);
        rdbtnOn.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void deactivate()
    {
        button0.setEnabled(false);
        button1.setEnabled(false);
        button2.setEnabled(false);
        button3.setEnabled(false);
        button4.setEnabled(false);
        button5.setEnabled(false);
        button6.setEnabled(false);
        button7.setEnabled(false);
        button8.setEnabled(false);
        button9.setEnabled(false);
        button_Div .setEnabled(false);
        button_C .setEnabled(false);
        button_Mul.setEnabled(false);
        button_Add.setEnabled(false);
        button_Sub.setEnabled(false);
        button_Dot.setEnabled(false);
        button_rec.setEnabled(false);
        button_Sqr.setEnabled(false);
        button_neg.setEnabled(false);
        button_per .setEnabled(false);
        button_equal.setEnabled(false);
        button_undo .setEnabled(false);
        btnExit .setEnabled(false);
        rdbtnOn.setEnabled(true);
        rdbtnOff.setEnabled(false);


    }

}
```

Its not working. Can someone help me.
Many thanks.

Comment: It's unclear for me what exactly your problem is. Can you add a **small** example code of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It is possible!!

Comment: If you want to do something easy with inheritance, instead of trying to get a little code hack to work just extend your class with a JFrame. Especially since your class is called `UIFrame` so it would make sense to extend from a `JFrame`. See `SimpleClass` from my answer below for an example

Comment: As far as I can see browsing your 600 lines of code (that was not what I meant by **small** example), the Activate_and_Deactivate class does not help much. Focus on the buttons. Make sub classes of JButton, for example `NumberButton` and `OperatorButton` which take the number/operator in their constructor. Then you do not have to copy/paste the same code for ActionListeners and styling again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not use your base class as an instance of your derived class.

However, you can store an instance of the derived class in your base class and then cast it back to the derived class when you need to. See the `ActionListener` on the button for an example

**Base**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleClass extends JFrame {
    public SimpleClass(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        setUp();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public SimpleClass() {

    }

    public void setUp() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        ExtendedClass e = new ExtendedClass();
        SimpleClass s = new ExtendedClass();
        SimpleClass thisInstance = this;

        JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(e instanceof ExtendedClass);
                e.printLn();

                System.out.println(s instanceof ExtendedClass);
                ((ExtendedClass)s).printLn();

                System.out.println(thisInstance instanceof ExtendedClass);
                //Returns an exception as it is not an instance of ExtendedClass
                ((ExtendedClass)thisInstance).printLn();
            }
        });

        panel.add(button);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new SimpleClass("Title"));
    }
}
```

**Extended**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ExtendedClass extends SimpleClass {
    public void printLn() {
        System.out.println("Printed A Line To The Console :)");
    }
}
```